# Getting Empty image,When Download from Dropbox to Android Sdcard

Tags: android, image, dropbox, android-sdcard

1. I want to download a Specific image from Dropbox,then Save into Sdcard.
2. After Button Click **folder is creating in Sdcard** , Image also Saving in that folder.

**Problem:**
 image Size is Showing as  **0 Kb**

clicking on image it Showing Black Screen.

Please help me to solve this Problem

**Button Click to Download a image**

```
Download.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {  
        File file1 = new File("/Photos/Picture_2015-07-06_13-41-04.png");//A specific Picture from Dropbox.
        downloadDropboxFile(file1);
}});

private boolean downloadDropboxFile(File fileSelected) {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MYfolder";

    File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();
    try {
        File localFile = new File(dir + "/" + fileSelected.getName());
        if (!localFile.exists())
        {
            localFile.createNewFile();
            copy(fileSelected, localFile);
        } else {
            //showFileExitsDialog(fileSelected, localFile);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}

private void copy(final File fileSelected, final File localFile) {
    final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(DBRoulette.this,
                    "Downloading...", "Please wait...");
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            BufferedInputStream br = null;
            BufferedOutputStream bw = null;
            DropboxInputStream fd;
            try {
                fd = mApi.getFileStream(fileSelected.getPath(),localFile.getPath());
                br = new BufferedInputStream(fd);
                bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile));

                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int read;
                while (true) {
                    read = br.read(buffer);
                    if (read <= 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                pd.dismiss();
                Message message = new Message();
                message.obj = localFile.getAbsolutePath();
                message.what = 1;
                //mHandler.sendMessage(message);
            } catch (DropboxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (bw != null) {
                    try {
                        bw.close();
                        if (br != null) {
                            br.close();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: You're catching and just printing out several exceptions. Can you post your output? Also, the [`getFileStream`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#getFileStream(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method takes two parameters, java.lang.String `path`, and java.lang.String `rev`. Make sure the first one is the path to the file in the remote Dropbox. For the second, you seem to be passing in another path, instead of a `rev`. You can use `null` to get the latest version.

Comment: How can i Make changes in my code